# Chimney damper does not open

Tags: chimney, flue

My chimney damper does not open. I bought the house last year so have never used it before. Any suggestions on how to get it unstuck? Note that the damper cable DOES move from one side to the other but it just does nothing to open the damper. Looking at it, I can't even tell how this is supposed to work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to slide that handle over to the larger slot and then pull it down or push it up.

Ok, good you got it. It was hard to tell from the picture which way it operated. You could try some WD-40 but these dampers are pretty cheaply made and don't have a precision fit. You should try working it back and forth to loosen it up a bit.

Comment: The narrow section of slot is to hold it in place.  Pull the handle away(out) from where it fits in larger section of slot as @JACK said.

Comment: So, it actually goes the other way. It should push up. I'm able to whack the side of the damper that the rod attaches really hard with a pole and then the damper opens. But once I close it again, it's stuck, and has to be hit with the pole again to reopen. Could it need lubrication or something?

Comment: You may want to beef up this answer a bit. Maybe include your comment in the answer itself...

Comment: WD-40 sprayed all around has got the damper moving now without TOO much effort. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Brian   remember:  WD40 is **not a lubricant** . Yes, sometimes it helps unfreeze things, but after that you should clean it all off and, if necessary, lubricate with graphite powder or silicone spray.  Given the potential high temperatures here, I would recommend against any kind of lubricant, and just clean & polish the sticking points.

Comment: Is it *possible* the damper has gotten pushed up past the stop, and that the open position(s) are supposed to be with the actuator rod pulled down? Does the entire damper rotate or does just one-half of the damper open as a flap?

Comment: @Jim The entire damper is one solid piece and rotates around a shaft in it's middle.

Comment: When you have the actuator rod pushed up as fast it will go is the damper plate vertical? Looks very clean. What fuel is burned in it--natural gas?

Comment: @JimStewart I've got just about the same damper as this and it opens about 55 degrees from horizontal. The sheet metal get a little warped from the heat.  Every Winter I get about 25 calls to open vents for seniors in my subdivision and in the Spring I get the calls to close them... I get paid with cookies and candy...